# How to create a color scale between two given colors in GNU R

Tags: r, rgb

I have two colors with RGB-codes like `a <- "#000099"` and `b <- "#CCCCFF"`

Let's say I need 10 colors, and these colors need to start with `a` and end with color `b`, and all the other colors are "between" these two with "equal distance"...

So, I am looking for something like

`giveColorVector(start="#000099", end="#CCCCFF", length=10)`

and this should return a vector like this:

`[1] "#000099" "0000FF" (...) "6666FF" "#7777FF" "#8888ff" "#9999FF" "#CCCCFF"`

How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `colorRampPalette` like so:

```
 a <- "#000099"
 b <- "#CCCCFF"
 colorRampPalette(colors=c(a,b))(10)
 [1] "#000099" "#1616A4" "#2D2DAF" "#4444BB" "#5A5AC6" "#7171D1" "#8888DD"
 [8] "#9E9EE8" "#B5B5F3" "#CCCCFF"
```

In place of `a` and `b` you could also use R's color names, such as `colors=c("blue","green")`, and you can use more than 2 colors if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? `colorRampPalette(c("#000099", "#CCCCFF"))(10)`

Comment: Thanks Matthew, that's it! I marked John's Answer as "correct", as I saw your post later...

Comment: Actually, I was first, but whatever.